# What are the differences between CGO invocations in the main package vs a module?

Tags: go, cgo, go-modules, bpf, bcc-bpf

I have written a BPF program that I can install using gobpf, i.e. using their bcc tooling. While this works alright from a main package, this breaks as soon as I move it into a package for importing it as a module.

To clarify: It works with all code in `package main`, but as soon as I rename the package and move the `main()` to `cmd/command.go` it stops working with `go run` complaining that it can't find an included lib (`bcc/proto.h`). Incidentally, this is the same error as I always got when running `gcc` on my `.c` file without any indication I want to use BPF (the part that `gobpf` did for me, until I moved its invocation to a module...).

I realize this is question very specific and sits in a weird place between Go, CGo, the way C and C++ handle includes, BPF, and bcc, but I am at a loss here.

You can check out my code here https://github.com/bwNetFlow/bpfdump if that helps. It needs `bcc` installed in addition to `go run` doing its thing. Basically:

- `HEAD` is the modularized version that *does not* work (`go run cmd/dump.go`)
- `HEAD~` is my initial experiment that *does* work (`go run bpfdump.go`) (you'll get an permission error as user, which is fine as it has compiled anyways).

PS: I think it *might* have to do with this (rather creative?) construction of `bcc/proto.h`: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/src/cc/exported_files.cc

Comment: Probably unrelated to your actual problem, but _please_ refrain from using `go run` with filename arguments: It is a loaded footgun for any project not consisting of a single file. Get used to do `go build` (or at the very least `go run .`).

Comment: I guess the problem is that when you move your `cgo`-using code into a subpackage `cgo` generates support files (or looks them up) in a place where they do not exist. The simplest way to see it for yourself is to run `go build` with the `-x` command-line flag (as @Volker said, never ever use `go run` unless it's a single Go "script" with no frills). Consider carefully reading [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo) while paying attention to how various directories are set up and communicated to the parts of the C toolchain.

Comment: @kostix You're both almost right, thanks for the eye-opener. I usually don't call go with files directly and I don't know why I did in this instance, but then it stuck in my history...

The precise issue was this sentence in the Docs you provided:

"When the Go tool sees that one or more Go files use the special import "C", it will look for other non-Go files in the directory and compile them as part of the Go package."

Which is what I didn't want to happen, as this C Code needs the context provided by the gobpf package.